# How to use jquery datatable on a table that is generated after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing an asp.net mvc 5 application in which, I've some textBox fields, the user will input these textbox fields, and the data will be generated in a table below those fields using javascript, when the user clicks the "Add" button one row will be added and so on, so, it is a table that is getting generated on the client side, this way :

```
$('#add').click(function () {

//textbox input gets pushed here in an array
//function that generates Html code of a table using javascript, Note that, id gets set here, this way :

//var $table = $("<table>");
//$table.attr("id","myTable");

//And, In the end, Datatable fucntion is called here
$('#myTable').DataTable();

});
```

The above code is written in the index view of the "Home", and the files that are needed to call jquery's datatable are added in the Layout.cshtml, this way :

```
//Before the body gets ended, these are the script files that are added

.
.
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/datatables/jquery.datatables.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
```

Now, my question is that, table html is getting generated fine but the datatable in getting called, datatable is not working, Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Any Help will be deeply appreciated, Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: If you are trying to add a row when user click, maybe [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) could help you.

Comment: Bilal, have you taken a look at the console log of your browser when you click #add? Might be some clues there as far as what is happening with either A: finding the element #myTable or B: initializing the datatable.

Comment: @mwwallace8, I checked in the console window, it is displaying an error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function` , but I think that I've added the datatables files fine in the _Layout.cshtml, then why is it showing me this error? and what should I do to resolve it?

Comment: @MoshFeu, Rows are getting added fine in the table, that is displaying an Html table, but I want it to display the Html DataTable and it is not doing this, In Fact, I've added the script files fine and called it at the right place in click event, but still no gain :( , it is also generating an error, please refer to my last comment..

Comment: You might double check that you are using the correct case-sensitivity for .dataTable. I believe depending on the version of datatable you are using the initialize function is camel-case (i can't see your version since its in a bundle)

Comment: @mwwallace8 Awesome, so, it was actually the bundle that was bothering me, I've added jQuery above in my code and the jQuery bundle was already added, which means I was adding jQuery file twice, therefore, they had the conflict. what I did is that I removed the jQuery file that I've added, and placed my jquery datatable files **under** that bundle file, and it worked :)